# Proofs on subspaces and null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n \times p$ matrix.

1. Prove that $null{AB} \subseteq null{B}$.
2. Give an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $null{AB} \not\supseteq null{A}$.
3. Prove or disprove: $CS(AB) \supseteq CS(B)$.
4. Suppose $m = n = p$, that $\det(B) \neq 0$ and there are $k$ linearly independent vectors in $null{A}$ for some $k \leq n$.  Show that there are $k$ linearly independent vectors in $null{AB}$.

My approaches:
I set up $x$ in $null(B)$, then $Bx = 0$, $ABx = A(Bx) = A(0) = 0 $
So $x$ in $null(AB)$. So, $null(AB) \subseteq null(B) $.

I need help on the proofs... thanks

Comment: I think you mean, $\operatorname{null}(AB) \supseteq \operatorname{null}(B)$.

Comment: I wrote it the same way on the problem... so I guess it is asking nullAB  ⊆ nullB

Comment: null means Ker ?

Comment: null space, we did not use ker in class tho